# GAE JSONP parameter size limits

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsonp

I'm writing a server side handler for JSONP request. It's a Java version of GAE.

My local dev server doesn't like the length of the query string.
I have to use JSONP as this will be a cross domain request.

Is there a limit on GAE for how long the query string can be? 
Is that a browser thing?

Do I have to split the request into many and maintain the state on the GAE Handler side?

Comment: I just tried the same request in the different browser and it seems it's a browser thing. Chrome was unable to handle request with query string more than 4000 characters. Firefox was ok with it. This question was useful as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string .

Answer (score 0):

If it's a really long request, you probably want to submit paramters via a POST request, rather than in the URL.